# How to insert into database through postgres sql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have below code to insert the values into database

```
db.one('INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_id) VALUES (a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11)')
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user.name); // print user name;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error, 'jjjjjjjjjjjj'); // print the error;
    });
```

I want to insert three fields

```
1) transaction_id 
2) amount 
3) currencies_currency_id
```

But getting error

`error: syntax error at or near "c0b"`

Please help what I am doing wrong here

Comment: If you want to insert3 fields then you should specify  those 3 columns and strings should be single-quoted. `INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_id,amount, currencies_currency_id) VALUES ('a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11', ?,?)`

Comment: Thank you but Giving me error `error: syntax error at or near "amount"`

Comment: what's `db.one` ? it's not part of PostgreSQL. which language is that ? tag that as well. My query should work in PostgreSQL when you substitute other values `(?,?)` correctly. I don't know how it works in your programming language.

Comment: @KaushikNayak It is nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think SQL value needs single quotes

try

```
db.one('INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_id, amount, currencies_currency_id) VALUES (\'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11\', \'enter amount\', \'enter currencies_currency_id\')')
.then(user => {
    console.log(user.name); // print user name;
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error, 'jjjjjjjjjjjj'); // print the error;
});
```

Comment: Thank you how can I insert second field?

Comment: Hi I need to call one for query to get details for particular user_id `"SELECT * from wallet WHERE users_details_iwant_user_id = 1"` But this doesn't work

Comment: When building sql statements in nodejs, I think you'll find it easier to use ES6 template literals. Also try typecasting your values to the types of the columns they are intended for.

Comment: @FirozShams `ES6 template literals.` What are that?

Comment: here you go https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Using template literals your query can be rewritten as `INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_id, amount, currencies_currency_id) VALUES ('${"a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11"}', ${29},'${"some currency id"}')`

Comment: Also I'm seeing that you did not specify your schema name in the statement. Assuming you're using the public schema, can you try public.transactions instead of transactions and see if it works?

Comment: Thank you @FirozShams +1